# 4x4 CSS Converting JPG file to GIF

Tags: php, jquery, css

How can I collect the above images in just one frame and do GIF? Can I do this using CSS and PHP?

[image]

I want to show these 4x4 images as a gif in just 1 frame.

Comment: As a `gif` specifically, not with css, but as an animation where it shows one image at a time, not hard with jquery / css.  If all the composite images are the same size / have parts in the same position, then it's just a div with overflow-hidden and set the margin to offset to each image.

Comment: Do you have a sample code in your hand?

Comment: I can't give you working code right now, but essentially `<div id='wrapper' style='width:150px;height:100px;overflow:hidden'><img src='..your image'></div>`    then js `$(function() { setTimeout(function() { $("#wrapper").css("margin-left", "-150px"); }, 2500); });`  (change width/height/margin to fit the smaller parts of the image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an animation of the first row. Changing the y-axis will move the image to show the second row. PHP or Javascript is not required.

```css
.animation {
  width: 317px;
  height: 174px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo7T3.jpg') 0 0;
  animation: play 16s infinite;
}

@keyframes play {
0% { background-position: 0 0; }
5.99% { background-position: 0 0; }
6% { background-position: -317px 0; }
11.99% { background-position: -317px 0; }
12% { background-position: -634px 0; }
17.99% { background-position: -634px 0; }
18% { background-position: -951px 0; }
23.99% { background-position: -951px 0; }
24% { background-position: -1268px 0; }
99.99% { background-position: -1268px 0; }
100% { background-position: 0 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working feedle for you by me.
Implemented on javascript, using jQuery library.

https://jsfiddle.net/271qnqrj/

**JS:**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        mygif: function(speed, width, height, verticalBorderWidth, horizontalBorderWidth) {
            speed = speed || 400;
            width = width || 315;
            height = height || 175;
            verticalBorderWidth = verticalBorderWidth || 5;
            horizontalBorderWidth = horizontalBorderWidth || 5;

            this.each(function() {
              var img = $(this).attr('src');
              var div = $('<div class="mygif" data-frame="1" style="width: ' + width + 'px;height:' + height + 'px;background-image: url(\'' + img + '\');"/>').insertAfter($(this));
              $(this).remove();
            });

            window.setInterval(function() {
              $('.mygif').each(function() {
                var frame = $(this).data('frame');
                if (frame == 16) {
                    frame = 1;
                } else {
                    frame++;
                }
                $(this).data('frame', frame);

                var posX = (width + verticalBorderWidth) * ((frame-1) % 4);
                var posY = (height + horizontalBorderWidth) * (Math.floor((frame-1)/4));
                $(this).css('background-position', -posX + 'px ' + -posY + 'px');
              });
            }, speed);
        }
    });

    $('.mygif').mygif()
})(jQuery);
```

**HTML:**

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo7T3.jpg" class="mygif" />
```

**CSS:**

```
img.mygif { display: none; }
```